# How To Stop htaccess conflict url with name and id

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite url like : `www.example.com/xyz/tour-2016-8` 
but last 2016 conflict with 8 (8 is tour id) and i am using this code in htaccess
    `RewriteRule ^xyz/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ xyz/offer-detail.php?pname=$1&id=$2`
    i have check again my this 2 rules conflicts using this code
`RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9_]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ tour-list-view.php t_cat=$1&t_id=$2&t_name=$3
RewriteRule ^best-offers/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)-([0-9]+)$ best-offers/offer-detail.php?pname=$1&id=$2`

Plz help to solve this

Comment: What do you mean by "last 2016 conflict with 8"?

Comment: if i remove 2016 from name then its working

Comment: Change the order in the first capture pattern or escape the dash (`-`): `RewriteRule ^xyz/([-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)-([0-9]+)$ xyz/offer-detail.php?pname=$1&id=$2`